# Plotly: How to remove the gap behind the tail of an arrow created with add_annotation()?

Tags: python, graphics, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

I am using the `plotly.graph_objects.Figure.add_annotation()` function to add an arrow into my plot - see a simple example code below:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_annotation(ax = 3, axref = 'x', ay = 2, ayref = 'y',
                   x = 4, xref = 'x', y = 2, yref = 'y',
                   arrowhead = 3)

fig.add_shape(x0 = 1, x1 = 3, xref = 'x',
              y0 = 1, y1 = 3, yref = 'y')

fig.add_shape(x0 = 4, x1 = 6, xref = 'x',
              y0 = 1, y1 = 3, yref = 'y')

fig.update_layout(xaxis_range = [0, 7], yaxis_range = [0, 4])

fig.show()
```

which renders the following image:

[image]

As you can see, there is a small gap between the left rectangle and the tail of the arrow. **Is there a way to remove this gap, so that the arrow starts exactly as specified by the parameters `ax` and `ay`?** I have tried looking through the [documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html?highlight=add_annotation#id0) to see if there may be other relevant parameters of the `add_annotation()` function but couldn't find clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
xanchor = 'right'
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_annotation(ax = 3, axref = 'x', ay = 2, ayref = 'y',
                   x = 4, xref = 'x', y = 2, yref = 'y',
                   arrowhead = 3,
                   xanchor = 'right')

fig.add_shape(x0 = 1, x1 = 3, xref = 'x',
              y0 = 1, y1 = 3, yref = 'y')

fig.add_shape(x0 = 4, x1 = 6, xref = 'x',
              y0 = 1, y1 = 3, yref = 'y')

fig.update_layout(xaxis_range = [0, 7], yaxis_range = [0, 4])

fig.show()
```

#### Explanation:

As per the [documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html?highlight=add_annotation#id0),

> **xanchor** – Sets the text box’s horizontal position anchor This anchor binds the `x` position to the “left”, “center” or “right” of the annotation. For example, if `x` is set to 1, `xref` to “paper” and `xanchor` to “right” then the right-most portion of the annotation lines up with the right-most edge of the plotting area. If “auto”, the anchor is equivalent to “center” for data- referenced annotations or if there is an arrow, whereas for paper-referenced with no arrow, the anchor picked corresponds to the closest side.

Even if there is no actual annotation text, a (place-holder) text field is still rendered (anchored to the `'center'` by default), which is what pushes the arrow tail. Setting the **xanchor** to `'right'` ensures that the arrow starts where expected, while the empty text field is pushed to the left of that.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation and/or documentation? How did you know/find this? Thanks!

Comment: @Brunox13 Plotlys [docs on annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/) shows an example with `xanchor="left"`, so a little intuition and experience told me that `xanchor="right"` would do the trick.

Comment: @Brunox13 So how did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: This solution worked great for me - what an astute observation! Before I accept the answer, I was hoping for a bit more of an explanation of why this works for anyone else who finds this question because even after I had seen the docs (before posting my question), it was not immediately apparent to me that this would be the appropriate parameter to solve my problem.

Comment: @Brunox13 Sometimes, some aspects of plotly are neither intuitive nor transparent. But having used this library for quite some time now, I've experienced that the developers have thought of almost anything. So of you think something *should* be working, it almost always does. So seek, and you shall find. Anf if you don't, then there's a growing number of us here to help. Not to forget that [plotly's own forum](https://community.plotly.com/) is fantastic as well!

Comment: @Brunox13 So really all I can say is that it works because it's designed that way.

Comment: I edited your answer to include an explanation that I believe would help someone like me (without as much experience with plotly as you have) understand why this is a working solution. ;)

Comment: @Brunox13 OK. I appreciate your attention to details.