# How to add arrows between the shapes in python plotly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I created a plotly figure with three rectangles having space between them. I want to add arrows between the rectangle shapes pointing towards the right as passed by the user.
How can I create arrows between the rectangle shapes?

Here is an example of how I want the figure:

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please refer to [Plotly: How to remove the gap behind the tail of an arrow created with add_annotation()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329669/plotly-how-to-remove-the-gap-behind-the-tail-of-an-arrow-created-with-add-annot).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. Posting it hoping it would help people in future:

```
fig.add_annotation(ax = x_axis_start_point_of_arrow, axref = 'x', ay = y_axis_start_point_of_arrow, ayref = 'y',x = x_axis_end_point_of_arrow,arrowcolor='red', xref = 'x', y = y_axis_end_point_of_arrow, yref='y',arrowwidth=2.5,arrowside='end',arrowsize=1,arrowhead = 4)
```